# How to set default Home Music folder in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, home-directory, music

How does one set a user's home Music (and also Documents, Pictures, Videos, etc.) folder to a directory on another local partition?

I note that other posts suggest editing /home/user/.config/user-dir.dirs to substitute, in double quotes (""), an alternative path reference (I used /media/user/devicename/dirname/Music) but this fails in two ways.  First, this causes the Music folder to disappear from the left pane of Nautilus. (The folder reappears when the original entry is reinstated.) Second, double-clicking on the Music folder in the right pane does not take one to the specified alternative directory.

If the Home folders were to have any utility, one might expect a context-menu entry for each to specify its location.  Let's just say this is a wish-list item.

Any thoughts would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does one set a user's home Music (and also Documents, Pictures,
>   Videos, etc.) folder to a directory on another local partition?

Create a new "/home" partition, copy folder and files from your existing home directory to the new partition an mount the partition at your home directory. Or do so specially with a music partition an mount it to your existing `/home/music` directory.